# How to pass a variable from a function to stripe webhook function in PHP / Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have built a website and integrated stripe elements to it with payment intent ... and I would like to activate a subscription to a user whenever the server get a charge.succeeded event from stripe webhook.
I have this code that get the unpaid subscription ID of each user and it's written on the payment intent so it gets called whenever the user tries to make a payment:

```
$subscription = Subscription::findByUid($subscription_id);
```

for example it can be: 60ad280fbc3b9
and if I do `echo $subscription` the output will be:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "uid": "60ad280fbc3b9",
  "user_id": "60a405d5be7b6",
  "plan_id": "58bd4b4d0d4c3",
  "status": "new",
  "trial_ends_at": null,
  "ends_at": "2021-05-25 18:17:55",
  "created_at": "2021-05-25 16:38:39",
  "updated_at": "2021-05-25 18:18:07",
  "metadata": null,
  "payment_claimed": "0",
  "current_period_ends_at": "2021-06-25 18:17:21",
  "timezone": "",
  "started_at": "2021-05-25 18:18:07",
  "last_period_ends_at": null,
  "error": null,
  "gateway": "stripe"
}
```

so everything works perfectly on the payment intent function level, I just don't know how to send this variable `$subscription` from the payment intent function to the stripe webhook function in order activate the subscription by executing this code;

```
case 'charge.succeeded':
        $subscription->start()
        break;
```

it always gives me this error :
`Call to a member function start() on null`

and if I try to print the subscription id, nothing happens so it didn't receive it from payment intent function.

Can anyone please help me with it?
Thank you

Comment: The webhook you are receiving is just like a POST - it includes some data from Stripe that you can use to identify the charge, customer, subscription etc. Check [the sample code](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build) in the docs on how to handle a webhook - looks like you're maybe already doing this, so you're almost there.  The POST includes an `Event`, which you probably already have; for [`charge.succeeded` $event->data->object is a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types?lang=php#event_types-charge.succeeded).

Comment: Then you need to work out how to find your `$subscription` from that `charge` - eg if you are storing the payment intent ID you could use that. Or maybe you are sending some metadata (like your subscription id) when you create the payment intent - that metadata will be in the charge from the webhook.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the subscription id in metadata, stored it in another variable and called in this line $subscription = Subscription::findByUid($newvariable); ... now it works perfectly.